# Spring 3.1 : Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: xml, spring, tomcat

Here's my applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

<bean name="documentTrashCleanerJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass"
        value="com.ye.cron.job.DocumentTrashCleanerJob" />
</bean>

<!-- Add to cron the job execution -->
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="documentTrashCleanerJob" /><!-- 
        run every night at 00 am -->
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/5 * * * ?" />
</bean>

<!-- Registering in the scheduler -->
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I just don't know why, but that error is ocurring in my output (it wasn't occurring, I just don't know what I'm missing...)

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:633)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:582)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:685)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2155)
... 38 more

org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 7 in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext-default-cron.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 225; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at com.ye.web.appserver.listeners.StartupServerListener.loadPlugins(StartupServerListener.java:75)
    at com.ye.web.appserver.listeners.StartupServerListener.contextInitialized(StartupServerListener.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 225; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you have the spring's jars on the classpath?

Comment: Yes, I've spring jars on my classpath.

Comment: The `beans` tag is not closed in your applicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 4):

As I said in the comments on your question :

The `beans` tag is not closed in your `applicationContext.xml`.

Just add `</beans>` at the end of your file and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
</beans> closing tag is missing from the very bottom of your applicationContext.xml. Marc-Andre is right.
```